How to use Django {% querystring %} with GET form?
In Django 5.1 {% querystring %} was added. Is there some way to use it with GET form?
For example, let's say we have template with:
<span>Paginate by:</span>
<a href="{% querystring paginate_by=50 %}">50</a>

{# ... #}

<form method="GET">
    <input name="query" value="{{ request.GET.query }}">

    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

Assuming that we are currently on localhost:8000/?paginate_by=50, how to change form so clicking Search won't delete paginate_by query parameter - so what I want is for example localhost:8000/?paginate_by=50&query=abc and not localhost:8000/?query=abc?
Before 5.1 I handled that via providing form with hidden fields based on GET parameters, but I am hoping that now more elegant solution is possible.

This isn't a proper usecase for the querystring template tag. You'd be better off asking something like "How to preserve query parameters in a GET form?" without mentioning the template tag.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I know how to preserve query parameters in GET form (and such a question would probably be duplicate), I was just hoping that querystring offers a new solution to this problem. As such "No, this is not appropriate use case, because of..." would be an acceptable answer.

This is not where you use {% querystring %} for. But in this particular case, you probably should use django-filter.


Is there some way to use it with GET form?

No., the {% querystring … %} template tag [Django-doc] is used to generate querystrings. This is not what a form element is supposed to do.
If you add a querystring at the end of the action=".." [mdn-doc] for a form that makes a GET request, then the browser will normally strip away the querystring.
You probably can make use of the template tag, and some JavaScript that thus when submitting the form obtains the data from the form, and from the {% querystring %} (or probably better, JavaScript's window.location.search), and mix these together. Then you thus prevent the default form flow, but it thus requires some JavaScript to handle it.
I would however advise not to manually render HTML forms if you are searching. You can use django-filter [GitHub] to automatically generate a filter form, that will thus preserve other options.

I disagree a bit with the part that form element is not supposed to generate querystrings, given that form is just manipulable representation of hyperlink (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element:the-form-element-2). Using window.location.search is the approach I took (at least for now) - I capture query params with const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search); and then loop over new FormData(formEl).entries() updating them.

@MatijaSirk: you can indeed pass a querystring as value in a single HTML element for example, but that that means the data in the querystring is thus wrapped a second time, and will probably only result in large querystrings that contain (percent-encoded) querystring data.

@MatijaSirk technically you could have created a Django form to handle all of this automatically (with paginate_by etc. declared as hidden fields). Regardless this is not the job of the querystring template tag since it's only task is to create a querystring, not to create form elements.

We can dynamically render all query parameters as hidden fields using Django's request.GET and a for loop in the template:
<form method="GET">
<input type="text" name="query" value="{{ request.GET.query }}">

<!-- Loop through all GET parameters dynamically -->
{% for key, value in request.GET.items %}
    {% if key != 'query' %} <!-- Avoid duplicating the 'query' parameter -->
        <input type="hidden" name="{{ key }}" value="{{ value }}">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<button type="submit">Search</button>


Hello, this works to preserve particular GET parameter, but doesn't really answer the question - the point is, that there can be a lot of GET parameters present (e.g. page, filter_by, order_by, etc.), so you need to add a lot of hidden fields (preferably programmatically, not by hand). Django recently got {% querystring %} tag, which solves this problem at least for non-form cases - question is, if similiar solution is possible for forms.
